# Handling CRUD models with one to many relation DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, one-to-many

I appreciate your help

I have 2 models with a realation one to many like this

```
class Header(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35)

class Detail(models.Model):
    header = models.ForeignKey(Header, related_name='details', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=35)
```

I would like to know if exist some package that handle internally the CRUD of the details within the header CRUD, for example:

If I make a `POST` to `app/header` with this JSON:

```
{
    "title": "title 1"
    "details":[
        {
            "description": "detail number 1"
        },
        {
            "description": "detail number 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

the app should create the header with `id = 1` and then the 2 details with `ids = 1,2` in the database

If I make a `PUT` to `app/header/1` with this JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title 1 updated"
    "details":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "detail number 1 with a change"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "detail number 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

the app should update the `title` of the header and the `description` of the detail with `id=1`

Then if I make a `PUT` to `app/header/1` with this JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title 1 updated"
    "details":[
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "detail number 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

the app should delete only the detail with `id=1`

And if I make a `DELETE` to `app/header/1`, the app should delete the header with id=1 and all its details.

I want to know if there is any package that helps me or do I have to implement all that functionality

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: Yes, there's the [drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) package.

Comment: thank you very much, I will try it